# Creating a Shopify App with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first time creating a Shopify App with Ruby so i have a few question, im trying to install using this command:

```
bundle install
```

But im getting this error:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: 
[!] There was an error while loading `my_app.gemspec`: cannot load such file -- my_app/version
Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /var/www/html/shopify_app/my_app.gemspec:2
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  $LOAD_PATH.push File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
 >  require "my_app/version"
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
. Bundler cannot continue.
```

This is what i have already:

my_app.gemspec

```
$LOAD_PATH.push File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
require "my_app/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "my_app"
  s.version     = ShopifyApp::VERSION
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.author      = "Shopify"
  s.summary     = %q{This gem is used to get quickly started with the Shopify API}

  s.required_ruby_version = ">= 2.3.1"

  s.add_runtime_dependency('rails', '>= 5.0.0')
  s.add_runtime_dependency('shopify_api', '>= 4.3.5')
  s.add_runtime_dependency('omniauth-shopify-oauth2', '~> 1.2.0')

  s.add_development_dependency('rake')
  s.add_development_dependency('byebug')
  s.add_development_dependency('sqlite3')
  s.add_development_dependency('minitest')
  s.add_development_dependency('mocha')

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|example)/}) }
  s.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test}/*`.split("\n")
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
end
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is the file `version.rb` located? It's either missing, or your load path or `require` statement is wrong.Those are the possible alternatives. The error message tells you Ruby cannot find `version.rb`, so start by figuring out where that file is, then add the location to the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `version.rb` file under your `my_app` dir duet othe error:

```
[!] There was an error while loading `my_app.gemspec`: cannot load such file -- my_app/version
```